# Subscribing an a method to and eventhandler with more parameter(s)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I can't find solution similar to what I expect to happen. How can I add additional parameter to the method i want to subscribe to?

Suppose this line below is the code that subscribe to mouseover:

```
Panel cagePanel = new Panel();
cagePanel.MouseHover += new EventHandler(frmMain_MouseHover);

void frmMain_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
    // I wanna add some 'int index' parameter after 'e' variable) 
}
```

What I really want is just like this:

```
void frmMain_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e, int index){ 
    strings[index] = "bla bla bla";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find solution similar to what I expect to happen. How can I add additional parameter to the method i want to subscribe to?

You can't. How would the code *raising* the event (`Panel.OnMouseHover` or whatever) know what value to provide?

If you know at the time you *subscribe* the event, you can use a lambda expression to basically delegate the call, providing the extra information:

```
// 10 is just an example here - use whatever value you want for index
cagePanel.MouseHover += (sender, args) => frmMain_MouseHover(sender, args, 10);
```

EDIT: To iterate over each control in an array and subscribe an appropriate handler for each, you could use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    // See http://tinyurl.com/3b2hoft for reasons behind the copy
    int index = i;
    array[i].MouseHover += (s, args) => frmMain_MouseHover(s, args, index);
}
```

I would personally try to avoid needing this, however - can you not detect the index via the `sender` part, potentially using `Array.IndexOf`?

Comment: Can I ask more? how can i coz I just made an array of control(Panel) and what i want if I add an eventhandler using click, I wanna pass the exact index of the sender. but the lambda expression you gave, only output only a specific index( alwas gave me 5). I really don't know how to implement this kind of stuff, coz i really need the index to the method.

Comment: @Jed: Well presumably you're looping, to add the event handlers, right? If so, I'll edit my answer appropriately. Note that it's generally regarded as good etiquette to use full English in comments/posts in Stack Overflow - "because" rather than "coz" etc.

Comment: Exactly. I'm in a loop. Thank you very much. BTW, i'm really sorry sir for my bad english.

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm. Thank you very much again Sir John.
If i just can like your answer 10x. But obviously, i can't. LOL

Comment: If I use int i=Array.IndexOf(cagePanels,sender). It always give me i=-1;

Comment: @Jed: Hmm... that's surprising. If you can create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, it would make an interesting separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but if the extra data you need is related to what sent the event, you could use the `sender` value.  For example, if you want to know the index in a list of controls of the item that raised the event, you could do something like:

```
int i = controlList.IndexOf(sender);
```

Comment: I thought that .IndexOf() works only in strings? coz i can't use it. It does not appear with intellisense if i use your code

Comment: That was just an example usage; it may not work in your particular case.  Point is you may be able to get any related data from the `sender` value and knowledge of the control structure vs. mangling the event handler signature.

Comment: @D Stanley I greatly appreciate your immediate response sir. I'm sorry for not specifying that i'm inside a for-loop in subscribing the controlClick event. 

And If I use int i=Array.IndexOf(cagePanels,sender). It always give me index=-1 whatever control i click in array of controls(Panel).

I already got the solution using lamda expression taught by Sir Jon Skeet. But i don't know how to use your suggested answer.But I will be very thankful if you can teach me another technique how to perform the one you suggested.